# TPL Task ContinueWith Result and Exception result in Unhandled Exception

Tags: .net, wpf, exception, task-parallel-library

I running a task with a ContinueWith that pulls double duty: Processes the results if the task completes successfully or an handles any exception if an error does happen.   But the below code will not handle any exception properly and it registers as unhandeled and brings down the program (shortened somewhat for posting so may not be perfect):

```
void _SqlServerDatabaseListLoader()
{
    _ClearSqlHolders(true, false);
    _SqlConnectionStringHolder.Database = "master";
    if (_SqlConnectionStringHolder.IsComplete)
    {
        //Could time out put on its own thread with a continuation back on the UI thread for the popup
        _TaskCanceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _TaskLoader = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            IsLoadingSqlServerDatabaseList = true;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_SqlConnectionStringHolder))
            {
                // Open connection
                con.Open(); //If this cause an error (say bad password) the whole thing bombs

                //create a linq connection and get the list of database names
                DataContext dc = new DataContext(con);
                return new ObservableCollection<string>(dc.ExecuteQuery<string>("select [name] from sys.databases").ToObservableCollection());
            }
        }).ContinueWith(antecendant => _SqlServerDatabaseListLoaderComplete(antecendant.Result, antecendant.Exception),
            _TaskCanceller.Token,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}

void _SqlServerDatabaseListLoaderComplete(ObservableCollection<string> DatabaseList, AggregateException ae)
{
    //Just show the first error
    if (ae != null)
        ToolkitDialog.ShowException(ae.InnerExceptions[0], ToolkitDialogType.Error, CustomDialogButtons.OK, "Error:", "Database List Error");

    if(DatabaseList != null)
        SqlServerDatabaseList = DatabaseList

    //Set the running indicator
    _TaskLoader = null;
    _TaskCanceller = null;
    IsLoadingSqlServerDatabaseList = false;
}
```

I am using the TaskContinuationOptions.None to pull this off, I assume that is correct.  This declared in the base class this above class inherits from:

```
protected Task _TaskLoader;
protected CancellationTokenSource _TaskCanceller;
```

If I run under a scenario that does not result in error, everything goes fine and I get my Database Listing.  But if there is an error, say someone gives a bad password for this SQL Server login credentials, the error is not handeled.

But if I removed the option to pass the Result parameter, everything works as it should and exceptions are caught:

```
void _SqlServerDatabaseListLoader()
{
    _ClearSqlHolders(true, false);
    _SqlConnectionStringHolder.Database = "master";
    if (_SqlConnectionStringHolder.IsComplete)
    {
        //Could time out put on its own thread with a continuation back on the UI thread for the popup
        _TaskCanceller = new CancellationTokenSource();
        _TaskLoader = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            IsLoadingSqlServerDatabaseList = true;

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_SqlConnectionStringHolder))
            {
                // Open connection
                con.Open();

                //create a linq connection and get the list of database names
                DataContext dc = new DataContext(con);

                //HAVE TO SET IN THE THEAD AND NOT RETURN A RESULT
                SqlServerDatabaseList = new ObservableCollection<string>(dc.ExecuteQuery<string>("select [name] from sys.databases").ToObservableCollection());
            }
        }).ContinueWith(antecendant => _SqlServerDatabaseListLoaderComplete(antecendant.Exception),
            _TaskCanceller.Token,
            TaskContinuationOptions.None,
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
}

void _SqlServerDatabaseListLoaderComplete(AggregateException ae)
{
    //Just show the first error
    if (ae != null)
        ToolkitDialog.ShowException(ae.InnerExceptions[0], ToolkitDialogType.Error, CustomDialogButtons.OK, "Error:", "Database List Error");

    //Set the running indicator
    _TaskLoader = null;
    _TaskCanceller = null;
    IsLoadingSqlServerDatabaseList = false;
}
```

I assume I am not fully understanding how TPL is suppose to work.  I tried creating more then one ContinueWith and that did not seem to make a difference.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that fetching `Task<T>.Result` will raise the `AggregateException` *at that point*, which occurs *before* you can actually grab the exception, and prevents your method from being called.

One option is to use two continuations - one for when an exception occurs, and one for when it doesn't:

```
    _TaskLoader = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        IsLoadingSqlServerDatabaseList = true;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_SqlConnectionStringHolder))
        {
            // Open connection
            con.Open();

            //create a linq connection and get the list of database names
            DataContext dc = new DataContext(con);

            //HAVE TO SET IN THE THEAD AND NOT RETURN A RESULT
            SqlServerDatabaseList = new ObservableCollection<string>(dc.ExecuteQuery<string>("select [name] from sys.databases").ToObservableCollection());
        }
    });

    // This method is called if you get an exception, and processes it
    _TaskLoader.ContinueWith(antecendant => _SqlServerDatabaseListLoaderFaulted(antecendant.Exception),
        _TaskCanceller.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

    // This method is called if you don't get an exception, and can safely use the result
    _TaskLoader.ContinueWith(antecendant => _SqlServerDatabaseListLoaderCompleted(antecendant.Result),
        _TaskCanceller.Token,
        TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted,
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The other option would be to pass the `Task<T>` itself (`antecendant`) as the argument to the method.  You can then check for `task.Exception`, and if it's not null, show the exception, otherwise, process the results.

Comment: Thanks Reed.  Very interesting.  I tried that actually and could not get it to go.  Thanks for the idea about passing the entire task but same thing.  It does not like the ".Result" - it gives a design time error that it does not exist (both situation).  Its strange.  If I use the _TaskLoader it gives me signature error saying that it cannot cast a Task to a Task<ObservableCollection<string>>.  If I set " protected Task<ObservableCollection<string>> _TaskLoader" I still get the error.  But if I do "var x = Task<ObservableCollection<string>>.Factory.StartNew(() =>...." it works.

Comment: @Ernie Before, you were setting `_TaskLoader` to your *continuation* not the original task.  That might be why you've got the type mismatches

Comment: AHHHH...that was it Reed!  I think that has been my problem all along including when I tried to break it out with two ContinueWith's before posting.  Both of your suggestions worked.  Appreciate all the help!!